# Cherrypy Essentials book still works?

Tags: python, cherrypy

The book [CherryPy Essentials](http://www.cherrypyessentials.com/) is published in 2007, im referring to the examples there, is it still compatible to latest cherrypy verions 3.2 or already outdated?

Comment: I wouldn't use that as a reference.  Best is to use http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/index.html  The documentation is good, and really if you just want to get work done, you hardly need to read any of it!  There's quite a bit to learn... so much I'd hate to learn a bigger framework and be expected to get things done! That being said, CherryPy can easily become your swiss army knife web application server from prototyping to large and complex, and is able to be used for both equally well.

Answer (score 2):

I really disagree with some comments here. The online documentation is not clear enough for me. I was using that, as well as the [CherryPy Users list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cherrypy-users) and the book you mentioned. I think that the change that bothered me the most was:

CherryPy 3.0

```
cherrypy.config.update(conf)
cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), '/', app_conf)
*cherrypy.server.quickstart()*
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

CherryPy 3.2.2

```
cherrypy.config.update(conf)
cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), '/', app_conf)
*cherrypy.engine.start()*
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

That being said, I think that the book is a great tool even for >=3.2 versions of CherryPy.